# Laravel radio form

Tags: laravel

i'm trying to implement this payment,changing the user->pay from a default value of 0 to 1,hoW? pressing the checkbox and changing his value. This will log into videos that can be watched only from that customers. Every time i try to enter the url ( i'm logged already ) it redirects to the home :(
PaymentsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class PaymentsController extends Controller
{   
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    /**
     * 
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('home',compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show()
    {
        return view('sub.payment')->with(Auth::user());
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(User $User)
    {
        return view('sub.payment', compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $request->validate([
            
            'pay'=>'required']);

            $user->pay = $request->pay;

            $user->save();

        return redirect()->route('/home')->with('success', 'Congratulazioni per l/abbonamento!');   
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/payments', [App\Http\Controllers\PaymentsController::class,'update'])->name('payments.update');
```

payment.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container" style="background: rgb(12, 22, 28)">
    <div class="card1"style="justify-content:center">
        <header class="header">
            <h1>ESTREMI PER IL PAGAMENTO</h1>
        </header>

        <div class="payment">
            <div class="card">
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><h5>IL TUO PIANO</h5></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><p> Paghi 29,99£</p></li>
                </ul>
                <label for="name" class="label1">{{ __('Nome') }}</label>
                    <input id="name" type="text" class="input1" name="name" value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}">
                <label for="surname" class="label1">{{ __('Descrizione del video') }}</label>
                    <input id="surname" type="text" class="input1" name="surname" value="{{ Auth::user()->surname }}">
                <form  method="POST" action="{{ route('payment.update', $user) }}">
                    <main class="primoInput" style="position:relative;">
                        @method('PUT') @csrf
                    
                        <input type="checkbox" id="coding" name="pay" value="1">
                    <label for="coding">Accetta </label>    
                    
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text"id="condizioni">
                            Codice di sicurezza Creando un account accetti che il tuo abbonamento abbia inizio immediatamente e confermi di aver letto e accettato le nostre Condizioni di utilizzo e l'Informativa sulla privacy e sui cookie. Il tuo abbonamento verrà rinnovato automaticamente al costo di 29,99 € e la quota ti sarà addebitata mensilmente tramite il metodo di pagamento da te scelto, fino a quando non deciderai di disdirlo. Puoi disdire in qualsiasi momento, ogni mese, selezionando “Disdici abbonamento” da “Il mio account”.
                        </p>
                            <button type="submit" class="buttonBig"> {{ __('ATTIVA ABBONAMENTO') }}</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>




    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Your update function processes some request data before redirecting you to the home view. It doesn’t show any views and shouldn’t (if you’re following Laravel conventions which you appear to be). What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: To see the page /payment with the checkbox that once will be tic and accept with the button,will redirect to the home page,with the table USER changed,the field Pay from 0 to 1

Comment: I refer to my previous comment.